# Blender Objects are rendered streched on the Z-Axis

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, objects, 3d-view

When I'm rendering my scene, my sun in the background is being stretched on the Z-Axis when being rendered. But when I'm in 3D view and I'm turning the viewport shading to rendered, I'm not having this problem. Please help, It's important to me.

[image: Faulty_Sun]

Comment: have you animated it?

Comment: As it stands it's a bit of a guessing game. Consider uploading your blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com